# In iTextSharp it is possible change the width & height of a PdfTemplate object. Can we do the same to an iText7 PdfCanvas/Xobject?

Tags: vb.net, itext, itext7

I'm converting some iTextSharp-heavy VB.net code into iText7, and a part of the old iTextSharp code changes a Pdftemplate object's width & height to adapt to a given situation.

Now in iText7, I have a PdfCanvas object bound to a PdfFormXObject serving the same role as the former PdfTemplate object. So far, so good.

But alas, I have this old code to contend with:

```
Dim oObjectTemplate As PdfTemplate = oContainerTemplate
dTemplateSizeIncrease = oObject.FontSize * 4
oObjectTemplate.Width += CSng(dTemplateSizeIncrease)
oObjectTemplate.Height += CSng(dTemplateSizeIncrease)
```

I tried looking into the robust documentation for an answer, but there's little wisdom out there to be found for converting iTextSharp to iText7.

By this point in the code, the object template (and its iText7 counterpart) have already been through a bit of logic and have certain values already set. I'm not eager to have to make a new instance to accommodate a size change.

So... is there a way to resize an iText7 PdfFormXObject once its been made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText 5 merely changes the bbox of a Form XObject, so it's totally possible to do the same thing in iText 7 - just set the modified `bbox` to the `PdfFormXObject` instance. Example code (it's in Java, but very easy to convert to C# or VB.NET):

```
Rectangle bbox = formXObject.getBBox().toRectangle();
bbox.setHeight(bbox.getHeight() + 100);
bbox.setWidth(bbox.getWidth() + 100);
formXObject.setBBox(new PdfArray(bbox));
```